# How to get Twitter trends using Python and tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, jupyter-notebook

I want to develop a Jupyter Notebook which on executing every time shows the top 10 Twitter trending topics in India in the last 24 hours.

I got everything set up:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(apikey,apisecretkey)
auth.set_access_token(accesskey,accesssecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

and when I run `trends1 = api.trends_place(23424848)`, it gives:

> AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'trends_place'

And if this attribute has been removed then what should I do to get my work done? Please help..

Comment: consider accepting the answer, even if u already solved your problem... it will help future readers. Thx! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `api` do not have this `trends_place` attribute.
If u check the documentation (https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#trends), you will see that instead of using `api.trends_place()`, the correct syntax is `api.` followed by the attribute `get_place_trends()`.

So, i suggest the following code to get the desired result:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(apikey,apisecretkey)
auth.set_access_token(accesskey,accesssecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

WOEID = 23424848

top_trends = api.get_place_trends(WOEID)
```

Note that `top_trends` is an dictionary inside a `list` of length 1. Treat it like `top_trends[0]['trends']` and so on to get specific values. Example:

```
top_trends[0]['trends'][0]['name']
top_trends[0]['trends'][0]['url']
top_trends[0]['trends'][0]['promoted_content']
top_trends[0]['trends'][0]['query']
top_trends[0]['trends'][0]['tweet_volume']
```

Answer (score 0):

To get [trending topics](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place) near a specific location on Twitter,

Once you've set up:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(apikey,apisecretkey)
auth.set_access_token(accesskey,accesssecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

use `trends = api.trends_place(WOEID)`  to get the 50 trending topics based on the l[WOEID](https://www.woeids.com/)